# PHP re-order sequence of arrays within an array

Tags: php

Hello i'm using PHP and I'm stuck trying to re-order an arrays with an array as per below i.e. I want contents of key[0] to move to key [1] and the contents of key [1] to move to key [0]. Anyone able to provide some PHP code for this ?

****Current Array containing Arrays****

```
Array([0] => Array (
          [name] => 1.jpeg, 
          [type] => image/jpeg, 
          [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename1.tmp, 
          [error] => 0, 
          [size] => 1000
         ),
      [1] => Array (
          [name] => 2.jpeg, 
          [type] => image/jpeg, 
          [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename2.tmp, 
          [error] => 0, 
          [size] => 2000
        )
     )
```

****Want to re-order arrays within the array like this****

```
Array( [0] => Array (
         [name] => 2.jpeg,
         [type] => image/jpeg,
         [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename2.tmp,
         [error] => 0,
         [size] => 2000
       ),
      [1] => Array ( 
         [name] => 2.jpeg,
         [type] => image/jpeg, 
         [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename2.tmp, 
         [error] => 0, 
         [size] => 2000
      )
   )
```

Comment: And what's the point in this?

Comment: You could do `[$array[0], $array[1]] = [$array[1], $array[0]];`

Comment: array_reverse($arr, true);

Comment: What if there are 3 items in the array?

Comment: See this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282592/php-re-order-associative-array

Comment: Thanks everyone, I used @ Jeto solution.

Comment: @u_mulder the reason I need to reorder the contents of the array because I am receiving images in the backend  that have been submitted by the user using a HTML via a form input.  The images will be displayed on the webpage in the order/sequence chosen by the user. I did not want to use jquery to allow the user to specify what sequence they wanted the images in so I just used vanilla javascript to create an array detailing what sequance the images are to be displayed and pass it to the backend. I then use this array to change the sequence of the images received from HTML form

Comment: @u-mulder it's because the user can't modify the sequence of images once they are set in the input type="file" tag, so if the user selects 15 images the are essentially sent to the backend using the POST method in whatever order the images were sorted by in the users local folder, i.e windows operating system might have images arranged by name or date created, etc. But when the user uploads them and they want one particular image to be displayed first then the image files data received in the backend needs to be re-ordered. It's a shame it can't be done on the front end using plain jscript.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you simply want to reverse the array key order? If so, you can just use `array_reverse()` for this.

Alternatively, if there's a pair of array keys you're trying to specifically swap, here's a function you can use that'll do exactly that for you:

```php
/**
 * Swaps two array keys over in the provided array
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param mixed $keyA
 * @param mixed $keyB
 */
function swapArrayKeys(array &$array, $keyA, $keyB)
{
    if (!isset($array[$keyA], $array[$keyB])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('One or more keys are missing from your array');
    }

    $a = $array[$keyA];

    $array[$keyA] = $array[$keyB];
    $array[$keyB] = $a;
}
```

Example usage:

```php
<?php

$inputArray = [
    [
        'name' => '1.jpeg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => 'C:\fakefolder\fakename1.tmp',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 1000
    ],
    [
        'name' => '2.jpeg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => 'C:\fakefolder\fakename2.tmp',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 2000
    ],
    [
        'name' => '3.jpeg',
        'type' => 'image/jpeg',
        'tmp_name' => 'C:\fakefolder\fakename3.tmp',
        'error' => 0,
        'size' => 3000
    ],
];

// Swap elements 1 and 3 in the array (keys 0 and 2 due to arrays being zero indexed)
swapArrayKeys($inputArray, 0, 2);

// Output the new array
print_r($inputArray);

/**
 * Swaps two array keys over in the provided array
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param mixed $keyA
 * @param mixed $keyB
 */
function swapArrayKeys(array &$array, $keyA, $keyB)
{
    if (!isset($array[$keyA], $array[$keyB])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('One or more keys are missing from your array');
    }

    $a = $array[$keyA];

    $array[$keyA] = $array[$keyB];
    $array[$keyB] = $a;
}
```

Console output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 3.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename3.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename2.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 2000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 1.jpeg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\fakefolder\fakename1.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1000
        )

)
```