# Offset by number in an array

Tags: php

I just can't figure it out, there is a code like this:

```
$a1 = ['k1' => '1', 'k2' => '2','k3' => '3', 'k4' => '4', 'k5' => '5'];
$a2 = ['k1' => '-1', 'k2' => '-2','k3' => '-3', 'k4' => '-4', 'k5' => '-5'];

$ix = 1; // number to move to
$k = 'k3'; // the key we want to move
$i = 1; // iteration number
$oldk1 = $oldk2 = '';
foreach($a1 as $key => $value) {
    if($k === $key && $ix != $i) {
        $oldk1 = $value;
        $oldk2 = $a2[$k];
        unset($a1[$k], $a2[$k]);
    }
    if($i === $ix) {
        $a1[$k] = $oldk1;
        $a2[$k] = $oldk2;
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

But it does not work, why I cannot understand what I was trying to do, I cannot solve this problem.

It consists in the following:

2 arrays with the same keys, but with different values, they must always go through the keys in the same order.

How to make it so that when I want, for example, that k3 stands in 1 place or on any other, I enter a number from 1 to the maximum in the array and so that in 2 arrays it is rearranged to the specified number and so that it is already like this:

```
$a1 = ['k3' => '3', 'k1' => '1', 'k2' => '2', 'k4' => '4', 'k5' => '5'];
$a2 = ['k3' => '-3', 'k1' => '-1', 'k2' => '-2', 'k4' => '-4', 'k5' => '-5'];
```

Comment: Why are you using an associative array if you care about the order of the elemtns? Use an indexed array.

Comment: @Barmar, you need an associative array

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282592/php-re-order-associative-array

Comment: @Barmar, Can you correct and formulate an answer for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving an array element by key to a new position. Here the index of the first element in the array starts at 1 as described in the question.

```php
$a1 = ['k1' => '1', 'k2' => '2','k3' => '3', 'k4' => '4', 'k5' => '5'];
$a2 = ['k1' => '-1', 'k2' => '-2','k3' => '-3', 'k4' => '-4', 'k5' => '-5'];

$k = 'k3'; // Key to move
$i = 1;    // New position index

// Retrieve the element with key $k
$element = array_splice($a1, array_flip(array_keys($a1))[$k], 1);

// Insert an element at a new position
$a1 = array_merge(
    array_slice($a1, 0, $i - 1), 
    $element,
    array_slice($a1, $i - 1)
);

// Rearrange $a2 keys and values by $a1 array
$a2 = array_merge($a1, $a2);

print_r($a1);
print_r($a2);
```

Comment: Excellent, offset!